# Is there a Design Pattern for Data Object structures that frequently change?

Tags: design-patterns

Is there a Design Pattern for Data Object structures that frequently change?

I am refactoring a Genetic Algorithm where the structure of the Chromosomes (number of genes, type of genes and boundary of genes) change from problem to problem.  For example:

One problem may use

```
class Chromosome{
    double gene1;  // 0.0 < gene1 < 100.0
    double gene2;  // -7.3 < gene2 < 9.0
}
```

Another problem may use

```
class Chromosome{
    int gene1;      // 200 < gene1 < 1000
    double gene2;  // 50.0 < gene2
    double gene3;  // gene3 < -5.0
}
```

Currently the chromosome structure is hard coded and is difficult to modify for a new problem. I am considering modifying the Strategy Pattern for chromosome changes, unless someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If chromosomes are just a collection of gene objects, they become easier to work with, especially if the boundary is also considered as an object.

```
public class Gene
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public Boundary Boundary { get; set; }
}

public class Boundary
{
    public double? Minimum { get; set; }
    public double? Maximum { get; set; }
}

public class Chromosome
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Gene> Genes { get; set; }
}
```

Then a new instance of a chromosome can be made simply by supplying it with a list of the necessary genes...

```
 var chromosome1 = new Chromosome
     {
        Name = "Biggie",
        Genes = new List<Gene>
                {
                  new Gene {Id = "1", Boundary = new Boundary {Minimum = 0, Maximum = 100}},
                  new Gene {Id = "2", Boundary = new Boundary {Minimum = -7.3, Maximum = 9}}
                }
     };

 var chromosome2 = new Chromosome
      {
             Name = "Fusion",
             Genes = new List<Gene>
             {
                new Gene {Id = "1", Boundary = new Boundary {Minimum = 200, Maximum = 1000}},
                new Gene {Id = "2", Boundary = new Boundary {Minimum = 50}},
                new Gene {Id = "3", Boundary = new Boundary {Maximum = -5}}
              }
      };
```

Since all the chromosomes now have the same structure, it becomes relatively trivial to make chromosome creation data driven.  The chromosome definitions can be stored in a config file or a database and new ones be added as needed. Each chromosome object can be populated via a simple loop that reads through the list of the genes it contains.

Comment: This solution will not work. The type of the gene value is not always double. It can be double, integer, boolean, or enumerated. Also if there are two gene each gene could have a different type for the value.

Comment: All of which will fit into a double.  You could also introduce generics, but it might not be worth the effort.

Comment: Lack of math support made generics more work than it was worth. Decided to use Double with min, max and increment. I will use an adaptor between the gene value and its interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to dbugger’s help, I believe I have a solution. I left off ID and Boundary for simplicity. IGene and Gene classes are the solution. TestGene is a test implementation.

```
public interface IGene<T>{
    //Accessors
    public T            getValue();

    public void         setValue(T value);
}

public class Gene<T> implements IGene<T> {
    //Attributes
    T           _value;

    //Accessors
    public T            getValue(){ return this._value;}

    public void         setValue(T value){  this._value = value; }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestGene {
    public enum EnumType {VALUE1, VALUE2}

    public TestGene() {
        IGene gene;

        List<IGene> chromosome = new ArrayList();

        gene= new Gene<Double>();
        gene.setValue(1.08);
        chromosome.add(gene);

        gene = new Gene<Integer>();
        gene.setValue(3);
        chromosome.add(gene); 

        gene = new Gene<EnumType>();
        gene.setValue(EnumType.VALUE1 );
        chromosome.add(gene);   

        for (int i = 0; i < chromosome.size(); i++ ){
            System.out.println( chromosome.get(i).getValue() );
        }
    }
```